# Where does AngleSharp IHtmlDocument exposes the doc's Uri?

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Where AngleSharp exposes the parsed document's Uri ?

Consider the following snippet:

```cs
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    string htmlString = httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.stackoverflow.com").Result;

    HtmlParser htmlParser = new HtmlParser();
    var parsedHtml = htmlParser.Parse(htmlString);

    Console.WriteLine(parsedHtml.Url);
    Console.WriteLine(parsedHtml.DocumentUri);
```

it will print `about:blank` twice.
The document is parsed, I can access properties such as Title, but I can't find a reference to its uri.

Did someone succeed in doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the only thing being passed to `AngleSharp` is string containing HTML. If you think about it, there is no way `AngleSharp` knows where did you get the string from (it can be from URL, files, or hardcoded as a C# string-literal).

To have `DocumentUri` works properly you need to find a way to load the document from URL in "AngleSharp way", probably using `BrowsingContext`. The following codes correctly print the URL for me :

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
    var task = BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
    var parsedHtml = task.Result;
    Console.WriteLine(parsedHtml.DocumentUri);
}
```

Comment: You are right, I thought about the fact that `HtmlParser` receives the string content of the response, after the uri was already retrieved.

Comment: There is a reason, however, why I opt to do the http request by myself (using HttpClient) instead of using AS infra. I want to have control over the http response status codes.

Comment: In any case, isn't it a problem that AS's framework allow you to instantiate a parser making thus these properties (uri and so) meaningless ?

Comment: I wouldn't consider that as a problem. It's just design decision. Imagine if the framework doesn't provide any way to parse HTML from string, only in order to keep the properties behave consistently...

Comment: IMO, the problem rather, that this behavior isn't well documented (at least, as far as I can find). Maybe you want to contribute on this :D

Comment: I duplicated this question on their project as well: https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/issues/319#issuecomment-208841925

Answer (score 0):

A cursory search of [AngleSharp for "DocumentUri"](https://gitlab.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=DocumentUri&group_id=&project_id=709508&search_code=true&repository_ref=35e7d7f5b30787ab0417ec650411569b5a11a2fa) results with [this](https://gitlab.com/Shushpanov/AngleSharp/blob/35e7d7f5b30787ab0417ec650411569b5a11a2fa/AngleSharp.Core.Tests/Library/DocumentEncoding.cs#L177):

```
[Test]
    public async Task LoadFromStringAndLoadFromUrlShouldResultInSameDom()
    {
        if (Helper.IsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            var config = new Configuration().WithDefaultLoader();
            var url = "http://imama.shop.by/kolyaski/detskaya_kolyaska_tutis_zippy_2_v_1_cvet_12_shokoladnyy223222222/";
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
            var response = await client.SendAsync(message);
            var html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var documentStr = await BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(m => m.Content(html));
            var titleStr = documentStr.Title;

            var documentUri = await BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(url);
            var titleUri = documentUri.Title;

            Assert.AreEqual(titleUri, titleStr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi pageman, I don't get how this helps... I would think simply accessing the property , which was made public, at any time would give me the uri, but it does not

Comment: @Veverke can you use document.DocumentUri ? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentURI)

Comment: no, as stated in the question's code snippet. Besides, the documentUri you are referring to is not part of AngleSharp's api ? (AS has one, and I tried that one to no avail).

Comment: I may not have mentioned it as a requirement, but I work with IHtmlDocument as the container of the parsed Html. I need the access to be through it.

Comment: @Veverke looks like you asked the right people! :) https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/issues/319